# How to open local html files in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1, browser

I downloaded whole website for offline browsing and now I'd like to somehow open it on my phone.

Is there a particular local URL format or a browser that supports this feature?

I tried to open it in IE from file explorer but it is not showing properly (it won't load any css or images) and there is no URL in address bar.

**UPDATE:**
Apparently, there are no browsers that allow access to local files. I did some research and it seems that browsers don't allow this feature due to limitations in SDK. Developing your own web browser control looks like the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna need an app with file access for that, as your browser can't open local files. I'm not sure if there are any apps yet as this kind if file access is only possible in Windows Phone 8.1.

There are however a few apps that let you donwload websites for offline consumption. Just check the store.

Comment: I know about apps that can save single wepages but in my case when I want to store website with thousands of html files, it's not very comfortable option.

Answer (score 0):

[Freda](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/freda/c1e312da-52d6-df11-a844-00237de2db9e) seems to do what you ask:

> It reads EPUB (DRM-free), FB2, **HTML** and TXT format books

I couldn't try it because I don't have a offline web site on my phone. But the App it's free, so give it a try!

Comment: Freda is a weird piece of software. It only provides access to multiple online services and to storage card! not a phone memory. My Lumia 925 doesn't support storage cards so Freda is not and option for me. I also tried to open html file in a few different filemanagers but it always opens the file in Internet Explorer and I haven't found any filemanager that has Open with... feature.

Comment: @neoproudek Sorry to read that. As I said, I didn't try it :-\